# JavaScript - variable initialized in constructor is not accessible in a method

Tags: javascript, class

This is my Api class. I initialize the variable **client** in init:

```
 export default class Api {
      constructor (options = {}) {   
        this.init()
      }
    
      async init () {
        this.config = await this.loadConfig()    
        this.client = this.initClient()     
        this.client.open()
      }
      initClient() {
           ...
      }
      loadConfig() {
      ...
      }
      fetchList() {
           console.log(this.client, this.config)
      }    
   }
```

Neither **client** nor **config** are accessible from the **fetchList** function. But they are initialized and have value when I console log them from the **init** function.

edit
I call fetchList from react useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
      let api = new Api()
      api.fetchTaskList({ type: 'active' })
      .then((data) => {
         console.log(data) 
      })
    },[])
```

Comment: You can’t have an async constructor. A factory would be helpful

Comment: How is `fetchList` called?

Comment: Examples of [How to do asynchronous operation in object constructor](https://bytearcher.com/articles/asynchronous-call-in-constructor/).

Comment: [Don't put asynchronous logic in a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24398699/1048572)!

Comment: @RaymondChen I call it from react useEffect. please check my edit

Comment: You're calling `fetchTaskLists` before `init()` finishes - you never `await` it anywhere.

Comment: @Bergi Where should I await it?

Comment: Don't call `init` from the constructor. Do `const api = new Api(); await api.init(); const data = await api.fetchTaskList(…);`.

Comment: However I recommend doing `const api = new Api(await Api.loadConfig(options)); api.fetchTaskList(…).…`, making `loadConfig` a static method and expecting the config as the constructor argument prevents wrong usage.

Comment: @Bergi Thank you I tried your first suggestion, and it worked